# Performance issue with immediate mode in OpenGL

Tags: c++, performance, opengl, graphics, glfw

How can this piece of immediate code be transformed to VBOs?

I have performance problems with my code, and I need help to make it faster by using VBO instead of immediate mode. Can someone show me how this could be translated to VBO to raise the performance?

This code is executed in the main loop `while(true)` of the code to draw a series of squares that may change its color to represent a matrix called `cmp`.
This `cmp` matrix represents a field from a snake game that may have NADA(Nothing), Snake, Apple or MURO(Wall), and depending of the value of the matrix it changes color on a switch.

I'm a newcomer to GLFW and Opengl so I don't know how to use VBOs and advanced graphical techniques.

The whole commented code can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/angelorodem/snake_engine/src) if you wish.

```
for(it a=0;a<(camp.Getlar())/2;a++)//line of quadrant -+
{
    for(int b=0;b<(camp.Getalt())/2;b++)//column
    {
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

        switch (cmp[a][b])
        {
        case camp.NADA:
            glColor3f(0,0,0);
            break;
        case camp.SNAKE:
            glColor3f(0,0.85f,0.20f);
            break;
        case camp.APPLE:
            glColor3f(1.0f,0,0.1f);
            break;
        case camp.MURO:
            glColor3f(0.3f,0.3f,0.3f);
            break;
        }

        glVertex2f(-1.0f+a/(camp.Getlar()/2.0f),        1.0f-b/(camp.Getalt()/2.0f) );
        glVertex2f(-1.0f+a/(camp.Getlar()/2.0f),        1.0f-(1+b)/(camp.Getalt()/2.0f) );
        glVertex2f(-1.0f+((1+a)/(camp.Getlar()/2.0f)),  1.0f-(1+b)/(camp.Getalt()/2.0f));
        glVertex2f(-1.0f+((1+a)/(camp.Getlar()/2.0f)),  1.0f-b/(camp.Getalt()/2.0f ));

        glEnd();
    }
}



for(int a=0;a<(camp.Getlar())/2;a++)//line of quadrant ++
{
    for(int b=0;b<(camp.Getalt())/2;b++)//column
    {
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

        switch (cmp[a+camp.Getlar()/2][b])
        {
        case camp.NADA:
            glColor3f(0,0,0);
            break;
        case camp.SNAKE:
            glColor3f(0,0.85f,0.20f);
            break;
        case camp.APPLE:
            glColor3f(1.0f,0,0.1f);
            break;
        case camp.MURO:
            glColor3f(0.3f,0.3f,0.3f);
            break;
        }

        glVertex2f(a/(camp.Getlar()/2.0f),        1.0f-b/(camp.Getalt()/2.0f) );
        glVertex2f(a/(camp.Getlar()/2.0f),        1.0f-(1+b)/(camp.Getalt()/2.0f) );
        glVertex2f(((1+a)/(camp.Getlar()/2.0f)),  1.0f-(1+b)/(camp.Getalt()/2.0f));
        glVertex2f(((1+a)/(camp.Getlar()/2.0f)),  1.0f-b/(camp.Getalt()/2.0f) );

        glEnd();
    }
}

for(int a=0;a<(camp.Getlar())/2;a++)//line of quadrant +-
{
    for(int b=0;b<(camp.Getalt())/2;b++)//column
    { 
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

        switch (cmp[a+camp.Getlar()/2][b+camp.Getlar()/2])
        {
        case camp.NADA:
            glColor3f(0,0,0);
            break;
        case camp.SNAKE:
            glColor3f(0,0.85f,0.20f);
            break;
        case camp.APPLE:
            glColor3f(1.0f,0,0.1f);
            break;
        case camp.MURO:
            glColor3f(0.3f,0.3f,0.3f);
            break;
        }

        glVertex2f(a/(camp.Getlar()/2.0f),        -b/(camp.Getalt()/2.0f) );
        glVertex2f(a/(camp.Getlar()/2.0f),        -(1+b)/(camp.Getalt()/2.0f) );
        glVertex2f(((1+a)/(camp.Getlar()/2.0f)),  -(1+b)/(camp.Getalt()/2.0f));
        glVertex2f(((1+a)/(camp.Getlar()/2.0f)),  -b/(camp.Getalt()/2.0f ));

        glEnd();
    }
}

for(int a=0;a<(camp.Getlar())/2;a++)//line of quadrant --
{
    for(int b=0;b<(camp.Getalt())/2;b++)//column
    {    
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

        switch (cmp[a][b+camp.Getlar()/2])
        {
        case camp.NADA:
            glColor3f(0,0,0);
            break;
        case camp.SNAKE:
            glColor3f(0,0.85f,0.20f);
            break;
        case camp.APPLE:
            glColor3f(1.0f,0,0.1f);
            break;
        case camp.MURO:
            glColor3f(0.3f,0.3f,0.3f);
            break;
        }

        glVertex2f(-1.0f+a/(camp.Getlar()/2.0f),        -b/(camp.Getalt()/2.0f) );
        glVertex2f(-1.0f+a/(camp.Getlar()/2.0f),        -(1+b)/(camp.Getalt()/2.0f) );
        glVertex2f(-1.0f+((1+a)/(camp.Getlar()/2.0f)),  -(1+b)/(camp.Getalt()/2.0f));
        glVertex2f(-1.0f+((1+a)/(camp.Getlar()/2.0f)),  -b/(camp.Getalt()/2.0f ));

        glEnd();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should take [a tutorial](http://learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Hello-Triangle) on this better. Anyway, what you achieve with VBOs is to upload all the geometry at once, using just one opengl call instead of calling a lot of `glVertex`.

If your geometry is constantly changing, *an option* is to update all the geometry at GPU on each frame, that will surely be faster than making all those calls on each frame.